# How to show only font-awesome icons on panel header?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, primeng

I'm using PrimeNG and simply trying to add font-awesome icons on panel header, but my issue is that if I delete the text (**LABEL**) a random css class shows up in the screen **ui-btn**. Can anyone point me in the right direction?.

**Here's my working code:**

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/gecFAR4gb2do7q6ZdXJg?p=preview)

```
<p-header>
  Registration Form
  <button type="button" pButton icon="fa-plus" style="float:right" label="Add"></button>
  <button type="button" class="ui-button-danger" pButton icon="fa-minus" style="float:right" label="Delete"></button>
</div>
```

**This is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:**

Comment: The HTML you show in your code doesn't seem to be reflected in the Plunker to which you've linked: https://i.stack.imgur.com/boVME.png

Comment: @DavidThomas yes you are correct. but if you get rid of the text (Delete or Add) you will see a random class name which is my issue, because I only want to show the icons and not the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the label property. I think what you're doing is set it empty (`label=""`) instead of removing it.

Try this :

```
<p-header>
  Registration Form
  <button type="button" pButton icon="fa-plus" style="float:right"></button>
  <button type="button" class="ui-button-danger" pButton icon="fa-minus" style="float:right"></button>
</div>
```

**Edit**
If you want something which looks like your picture, you need to customize with CSS and no need to use primeNG buttons anymore :

HTML :

```
<div id="header">
  <a (click)="refresh()"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-border fa-2x"></i></a>
  <a><i class="fa fa-bars fa-border fa-2x"></i></a>
  <a><i class="fa fa-expand fa-border fa-2x"></i></a>
  <a><i class="fa fa-minus fa-border fa-2x"></i></a>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
<div id="header">
  <a (click)="refresh()"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-border fa-2x"></i></a>      
</div>
```

See working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xpdT30ZRjT3V8fn2OeUe?p=preview)

Comment: how to make the buttons look like the ones from my picture? white background and blue border?

Comment: If you want something which looks like your picture, you need to customize with CSS and no need to use primeNG buttons anymore (see my edit)

Comment: @Thanks a lot for your input bro!!

Comment: My pleasure ! :)

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was the attribute "iconpos" associated with the button tag.
This show the ui-btn label:

```
<button type="button" pButton iconPos="left" icon="fa fa-plus-circle" (click)="addCustomer()" style="float:left;margin: 5px;"></button>
```

This for my app works:

```
<button type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-plus-circle" (click)="addCustomer()" style="float:left;margin: 5px;"></button>
```